# mysql usr-defined data type for table

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql and I am aware of basic data types in mysql. I am using it to create a webapp.

I want to create a table in which a particular field can have list of values. For example :
 UserDB ( ID, name, list_of_phone_numbers, list_of_interests ).

In above example,

1) There can be only 1 name. But there can be multiple phone numbers. How can I create list of phone numbers for the 'user' in same row/record.
2) Also phone number can have different parts i.e. ISD code, STD code etc.

To put it differently, can I have user-defined( created using basic data types)  data type as table fields? Is there something like 'struct' in C/C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would create a list of phone numbers using a junction table, with one row per phone number and user.  It might look something like this:

```
create table UserPhones (
    UserPhoneId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    UserId int not null references Users(UserId),
    PhoneTypeId int not null references PhoneTypes(PhoneTypeId),
    PhoneNumber varchar(255),
    constraint unq_userid_phonetype unique (UserId, PhoneTypeId),
    constraint unq_userid_phonenumber unique (UserId, PhoneNumber)
);
```

`PhoneType` would be a reference table that contains things like "home", "work", "mobile", "skype", or whatever.